# How to convert Panel to Word Document?

Tags: c#, ms-word, panel

I am looking convert a panel into a modifiable Word Document. How can I do this or something similar?  I tried googling this but not a lot of matches.

Comment: I think more details are needed.

Comment: I have labels and charts in my panel. I like the users to modify this panels so I am allowing users to export it to a Word file to enable them to makes changes to the report like font size, add lines, resize charts, etch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use word interop.

If I understand well, you want to create a word document, adding texte, and register in your desk(or somewhere else)?

Look at this msdn library : [Word.Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

You will be able to create a word document, and append text you want.